# Laravel Model: boot on trait and model

Tags: laravel, laravel-models

I have some Laravel models using the next Trait which is calling the model's boot method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait Uuids
{
  /**
   * Boot function from Laravel.
   */
  protected static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($model) {
      if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) {
        $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();

        if ($model->consecutive) {
          $model->consecutive = $model->max("consecutive") + 1;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get the value indicating whether the IDs are incrementing.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function getIncrementing()
  {
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Get the auto-incrementing key type.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getKeyType()
  {
    return "string";
  }
}
```

But on one of the models I have a `consecutive` column which I need to autoincrement and I was doing that with the boot function in the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Order extends Model
{
  use HasFactory, Uuids;

  public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
      $model->consecutive = $model->max("consecutive") + 1;
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that only the trait's `boot()` is being called. Is there another way fill the `consecutive` column of my model or call `boot()` method on both files?

Comment: a question: can't you make `consecutive` column as an auto incremented column on the DB level instead of incrementing it manually in the code ? Am just being curious (if you don't mind of course).

Comment: @ths sorry for the stupid question but, is that possible if I'm using an UUID string column as primary key?

Comment: Yes, just make the auto incremented column as an index (with auto_increment as well obviously).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `boot` function in the `Uuids` will not be triggered and to fix this issue, there is an awesome hidden feature in Laravel that says if the function name in your trait was `bootYourTraitName` it will be triggered with the boot model function, like so

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait Uuids
{
  /**
   * Boot function from Laravel.
   */
  protected static function bootUuids()
  {
    static::creating(function ($model) {
      if (empty($model->{$model->getKeyName()})) {
        $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();

        if ($model->consecutive) {
          $model->consecutive = $model->max("consecutive") + 1;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```